# Returning a 1.0f gives me 1065353216

Tags: c, floating-point

I have a C function that returns a type `float`.

When the function returns `1.0f`, the receiver sees `1065353216`, not `1.0`.

What I mean is, the following:

```
float Function()
{
    return 1.0f;
}

float value;
value = Function(); 
fprintf(stderr, "Printing 1.0f: %f", value);
```

Displays:

```
1065353216
```

But not:

```
1.0
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is the code you're compiling/testing? Please provide more context.

Comment: Interestingly, 1065353216 is the integer representation of 1.0 (IEEE single precision). Maybe your compiler or standard library has a bug, where it's interpreting %f like %d?

Comment: Looks like a `%d` was magically replaced by `%f` so nothing looks wrong here…

Comment: Does this help?

http://stackoverflow.com/q/1561243/365102

Comment: Wow! Trivial answer converted to comment! Is this new?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You define your function in one  source file and call it from another one not providing the signature making the compiler think that the signature is `int Function()`, which leads to strange results.

You should add the signature: `float Function();` in the file where the `printf` is.

For example:

```
float Function();
float value;
value = Function(); 
fprintf(stderr, "Printing 1.0f: %f", value);
```

Comment: Awesome, I wouldn't have thought of something like this… Seems like a good guess :)

Comment: Or you could use a header file.

Comment: @James its the same problem if you think about it: `Function` returns what it thinks is `1.0f` in some register (AX if I remember right), then main program thinks there's an `int` there. Effect is similar to that when you pass a `float` to `printf` with a "%d" formatting string.

Comment: Quick tests on an 32-bit x86 platform show the problem only in the situation described in the answer - using `%d` as the format specifier prints `0`. Maybe if the system were big endian, or one where `int` is 64 bits, the `%d` might actually produce the described output.

Comment: @Michael it's because `float`s get promoted to `double` inside `printf` and other non-declared functions. In the Op's question changing `float` to `double` changes the output to zero too.

Answer (score 4):

Double check your work, as your implementation is correct.

Evidence: http://codepad.org/QlHLEXPl

Comment: ..get real!  More seriously, some compilers/linkers/libs/whatever allow builds with printf/scanf, (and variants thereof), FP support disabled, (useful on embedded h/w with limited RAM).  I don't know what happens if such a build with FP disabled calls printf with a %f float format?

Answer (score 0):

My turn to guess the problem:

You are either:

- editing the source code without saving it
- editing one file but compiling and running another one
- editing and compiling one file but running another one
- doing something even more complicated but similar :)